# Can I rip the screen off the Adafruit Mini Color TFT with Joystick FeatherWing?

Tags: tft

I'm looking for a small color screen, and I came across  the [Adafruit Mini Color TFT with Joystick FeatherWing](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3321). But I want it to be a bit smaller, and I don't need the joystick and buttons on it. Would it be safe, and if so, how would I take off the screen and use that separately?

Comment: How much smaller do you want it? there's a version without the joystick. https://www.adafruit.com/product/3533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. The display is soldered to the PCB with a somewhat fragile flexible cable. You may have a hard time detaching the display and desoldering the cable without damage.

If you want the bare display without the carrier board at all, you can source those directly. Search for "ST7735 160x80" on your favorite Chinese marketplace -- this controller is used with a range of displays, and the 80x160 color display used by Adafruit is among them.

If you want the display on a carrier board without the buttons or joystick, [Adafruit sells that too](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3533).